# change blog title to an image using filter

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hey guys i'm trying to change the blog title to an image.

[image]

This is what I'm trying to achieve

[image]

I tried adding this code to the css and it's working.

```
.rh-content {
text-indent: -9999px;
background: url(http:file-location.png) 10px 10px no-repeat;
/* height: 100%; */
}
```

This is the result 
[image]

The image is not showing enough. But I want to add it to the functions.php in my child theme. i Tried this code

```
add_filter('the_title', function($title){ 
$title = '<img src="'. get_template_directory_uri() .'/images/blah.png">' . 
$title;
return $title;
}); ?>
```

but this is the result. This is what i'm seeing when i add the filter function

[image]

This is the raw code

```
<div class="rh-content">
            <?php if (is_author() || is_archive() || is_day() || is_tag() || is_category() || is_month() || is_day() || is_year()): ?>
                <h1 style="<?php echo esc_attr($styles_title); ?>">
                    <?php if (is_category()): ?>
                        <?php echo single_cat_title("", true); ?>
                    <?php elseif(is_tag()): ?>
                        <?php echo single_tag_title("", true); ?>
                    <?php elseif(is_day()): ?>
                        <?php echo get_the_date('F dS Y'); ?>
                    <?php elseif(is_month()): ?>
                        <?php echo get_the_date('Y, F'); ?>
                    <?php elseif(is_year()): ?>
                        <?php echo get_the_date('Y'); ?>
                    <?php elseif(is_author()): ?>
                        <?php $userdata = get_userdata($GLOBALS['author']); ?>
                        <?php echo esc_html__("Articles posted by", 'thebuilders'); ?> "<?php echo esc_attr($userdata->first_name)." ".esc_attr($userdata->last_name); ?>"
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <?php echo esc_html__("Posts", 'thebuilders'); ?>
                    <?php endif ?>
                </h1>
                <div style="<?php echo esc_attr($styles_breadcrumbs); ?>" class="nz-breadcrumbs nz-clearfix"><?php thebuilders_ninzio_breadcrumbs(); ?></div>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?php if (isset($GLOBALS['thebuilders_ninzio']['blog-title']) && !empty($GLOBALS['thebuilders_ninzio']['blog-title'])): ?>
                    <h1 style="<?php echo esc_attr($styles_title); ?>"><?php echo esc_attr($GLOBALS['thebuilders_ninzio']['blog-title']); ?></h1>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <h1 style="<?php echo esc_attr($styles_title); ?>"><?php echo esc_html__("Posts", 'thebuilders'); ?></h1>
                <?php endif ?>
                <div style="<?php echo esc_attr($styles_breadcrumbs); ?>" class="nz-breadcrumbs nz-clearfix"><?php thebuilders_ninzio_breadcrumbs(); ?></div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
```

This is the url link. https://harborllc.wpengine.com/blogs/

Thank you very much guys

Comment: link not working required auth.

Answer (score 0):

I just replaced the code to javascript

```
jQuery(function($) {
$('.rh-content h1').replaceWith(function(){
    return $('<img src="https://harborllc.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Harbor-Enterprises-Logo-Transparent-White-Outline-Revised-2.png"/>', {
        html: this.innerHTML
    })
})
});
```